# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS Windows

Tags: ros, windows, win-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anybody have complied ROS installer for windows. If the cross compiling for windows is standard, can anybody share your already cross compiled ROS? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10378/ros-windows/) by [thuniv](https://answers.ros.org/users/743/thuniv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-06-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Update

It is possible to install and use ROS Lunar on Windows 10 thanks to WSL:
http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows

This is the best way to use ROS on Windows right now, though it is not perfect.

---

The [Windows installation page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Windows) links to useful information regarding ROS on Windows. Please be aware that ROS on Windows is still very experimental. If you want the full "ROS experience", you should consider installing Linux.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-07**:
I believe it's important to recognise that ROSonWSL is not the same as having a native Win32/64 ROS. WSL does not have the same level of access to Windows resources, so 'driver' components wanting to access hw (usb, gpus for gpgpu fi) will not work (easily).